# LaTeXindent fail in VSCode: Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, vscode-extensions, log4perl

I'm using LaTeX Workshop on VSCode to build pdf using LaTeX and I'm getting this error in the Output console when I save the .tex file.

> Formatting with command latexindent
> -c,d:path_to_folder,d:path_to_folder/__latexindent_temp.tex,-y=defaultIndent:
> '    '
>
> Formatting failed with exit code 2
>
> stderr: Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Log::Log4perl module) (@INC contains: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/latexindent C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib) at C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/LogFile.pm line 22.

The problem is only related to the formatting stuff because the build runs successfully generating the pdf as supposed.

What I did:

- Opened the CPAN Client of my Windows 10
- Run `install Log::Log4perl` (it installed also other packages like `Log::Dispatch::File` and
  `YAML::Tiny`)
- Rebooted the system
- Checked that Log4perl is installed and it is

I also tryied to install Log4perl through VSCode cmd but I'm getting this wierd error:

```
Running make for E/ET/ETJ/Log-Log4perl-1.53.tar.gz
to undefined at C:/Perl64/site/lib/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 141.
make: *** [pm_to_blib] Error 255
  ETJ/Log-Log4perl-1.53.tar.gz
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe" -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 ETJ/Log-Log4perl-1.53.tar.gz                 : make NO
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in the end! To solve the error do:

1. Download **latexindent.exe**
2. Edit **Latex-workshop › Latexindent:
   Path** in the Latex Workshop VSCode extension settings with the
   latexindent.exe path

Comment: Yes, for Windows users, this is what I recommend, no perl required. (author of latexindent)